# A question about symmetric and alternating group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ symbols (i.e., the group of permutations of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, and $A_n$ be the subgroup of even permutations. Which of the following is true?
>
> (a) There exists a finite group which is not a subgroup of $S_n$ for any $n \geq 1$.
>
> (b) Every finite group is a subgroup of $A_n$ for some $n\geq1$.
>
> (c) Every finite group is quotient group of $A_n$ for  some $n \geq 1$.
>
> (d) No finite abelian group is a quotient of $S_n$ for $n>3 $.

**my attempt with my knowledge:**  every finite group is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of  $S_n$ and $S_n$ is ismorphic subgroup of $A_{n+2}$
so Every finite group is a subgroup of $A_n$ for any $n\geq1$

but i am not sure about my answer and and other options any help me please

Comment: You do know that $A_n$ is usually a simple group?

Comment: You've got to take care and not confuse "for some n" with "for any n".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown..yes i know that $A_n$ is simple group

Comment: We can only form quotient groups using normal subgroups.  I.e. valid quotients of $S_n$ are of the form $S_n/N$ for a normal $N \leq S_n$.  What are the normal subgroups for $S_n$?  The associated quotient groups?

Comment: $(d)$ is trivial, if you think about. You only need to know that $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ of index $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) As you said in your post, this is not true by Cayley's Theorem which states that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. You can look at the left regular action of $G$ on $G$ and identify it with a subgroup of $S_n$ where $n$ is the order of the group $G$. Usually, you can embed your finite group $G$ for a smaller value of $n$ but this suffices.

(b) True. If $G$ can be embedded into $S_n$, you can embed it into $A_{2n}$. For example, if you have $C_2\cong\{e,(12)\}$ then you can embed it into $A_4$ as $\{e,(1 2)(34)\}$.

(c) As mentioned in the comments by @Lord Shark the Unknown, since $A_n$ is simple for $n>4$, this is false. You can only get the quotient groups that you get from $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$.

(d) Unless, I am interpreting the question wrong, @Dietrich Burde has already given us a counterexample to this. $S_n/A_n\cong C_2$ and $C_2$ is certainly an abelian group.

Comment: @daruma..thank you lot